# Ayuda con esta cadena para guardar en SQL

Tags: sql-server

Me Podrían ayudar a encontrar el error en esta cadena, estoy usando Visual Basic

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CodigoProducto,Nombre,Compra,Venta,Stok,Fecha,Impuesto,idCategoria,idProveedor) 
 VALUES (" & ID & ",' " & nombre & " ',' " & Compra & " ',' " & Venta & " ',' " & Stok & " ',' " & Fecha & " ', " & Impuesto & ",' " & Categoria & " ',' " & Proveedor & " ')
```

En el apartado Fecha me sale este error: conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type in sql server

Mi tabla es la siguiente:

CodigoProducto varchar(12)

Nombre varchar(50)

Compra money

Venta Money

Stok int

Fecha smalldatetime

Impuesto float

idCategoria int

idProveedor int

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: los unicos campos que van entre comillas simples, son las cadenas...

Comment: Gracias gbianchi Ya lo pude solucionar.

Comment: Entonces elimina esta pregunta, porque esta destinada a ser cerrada, porque en realidad no tiene una solucion mas que ese comentario... tratemos de mantener el sitio limpio.. y lee los enlaces que te pase. Bienvenido!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses datetime2(7) para la fecha, y para guardar los datos desde visual basic podrías usar un string.Format, que convierte el valor de los objetos en cadenas en función de los formatos especificados y los inserta en otra cadena.

Ejemplo:

```
Dim cmd As String = String.Format("insert into productos (valor1,valor2) values ('{0}','{1}')", var1, var2)
```

Lo puedes hacer con todos los valores que quieras. Saludos